# Admin dashboard for Wordpress not loading: Table: 'wp_ppress_sessions' doesn't exist for query

Tags: wordpress

I recently tried updating my wordpress version and plugin versions and my website stopped loading.  I had made a backup prior to updating and when I attempted to rollback to the previous version, I thought I was successful however when I sign into my website, I see a 502 error.  The website is still working fine, but the admin dashboard fails once I sign in.

I was able to access my server's logs and see the error was:

```
PHP message: WordPress database error Table 'x.wp_ppress_sessions' doesn't exist for query SELECT * FROM wp_ppress_sessions WHERE session_key = 'eef418312eafa85dd942359b0d88caf63f4' made by require('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('plugins_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, ProfilePress\Core\Classes\PPRESS_Session->init, WP_PPress_Session::get_instance, WP_PPress_Session->__construct, WP_PPress_Session->read_data, WP_PPress_Session_Utils::get_sessionPHP message: WordPress database error Table 'x.wp_ppress_customers' doesn't exist for query SELECT * FROM wp_ppress_customers WHERE user_id = 1 made by wp_signon, do_action('wp_login'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\StatSync->ProfilePress\Core\Membership\{closure}, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\StatSync->core_actions, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\Models\Customer\CustomerFactory::fromUserId, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\Repositories\CustomerRepository->retrieveByUserIDPHP message: WordPress database error Table 'x.wp_ppress_orders' doesn't exist for query SELECT COUNT(id) FROM wp_ppress_orders WHERE 1=1 AND status IN ('completed')  ORDER BY id DESC made by wp_signon, do_action('wp_login'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\StatSync->ProfilePress\Core\Membership\{closure}, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\StatSync->core_actions, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\Models\Customer\CustomerEntity->recalculate_stats, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\Repositories\OrderRepository->retrieveByPHP message: WordPress database error Table 'x.wp_ppress_orders' doesn't exist for query SELECT SUM(total) FROM wp_ppress_orders WHERE customer_id = 0 AND status = 'completed' made by wp_signon, do_action('wp_login'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, ProfilePress\Core\Membership\StatSync->ProfilePress\Core\Membership\{closure}, ProfilePress\Core\Member
```

It seems like the table `wp_ppress_sessions` or `wp_ppress_orders` is missing?  Is there any way to recover something like this?  Worth mentioning, I'm not sure what the `wp_ppress_orders` table is for, looks like it might be related to `wp-user-avater` that my site does use.

Comment: The `ppress` prefix (midfix?) seems to be used by [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/). The group that makes it is called "Profile Press" so I'm guessing that's where they got `ppress`. Their support channels might be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to FTP into my server and change the name of the `/plugins` folder to `/plugins.hold`.  This allowed me to access my wp-admin dashboard and manually re-activate each plugin.